# How to find a path using two words in bash shell Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to locate a path using to words for example I want to have this path given /home/user/build-ledindicator-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/ when I search for "build" and "ledindicator" in a same condition.
I used to use locate ledindictor and it gives me the path, but in my case I have more than one path have ledindicator in it
Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: if these two words are supposed to be in the same filename a single find command, `find -name "*build*" -name "*ledindicator*"`, would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does thsi work for you?

```
find / -name "*ledindicator*" |grep "build"
```

much slower than `locate` but you can pipe more conditions to match with `grep`

Also if by`path` you mean `directories` only, you can add `-type d` after the `/` in the command to search only for folders.

Comment: i would recommend to search at least in /home/user `find ~`

Comment: That is up to him. since he mentioned `locate` which maps the whole disk, that is why I suggested `/`, he can adjust this `find` command in many ways :)

Comment: `/` isn't a disk and i doubt `locate` searches in */tmp /usr/tmp /var/tmp ...* and `find` will give lot permission errors on various paths ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Use Find's Logical AND Operator

You can do this in pure *find* (both BSD and GNU) by using the logical AND operator. From the BSD manpage:

> expression **-and** expression
> expression expression
>
> The **-and** operator is the logical AND operator.  As it is implied
> by the juxtaposition of two expressions it does not have to be
> specified.  The expression evaluates to true if both expressions
> are true.  The second expression is not evaluated if the first
> expression is false.

For example:

```
$ find . -path "*build*" -path "*ledindicator*"
./build-ledindicator-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
```

Comment: It did not return anything neither a path nor an error

Comment: It works fine. `.` checks the current working directory on down. Replace `.` with the top-level path you want to start from, e.g. `"$HOME"`. You may also need `-H` if you're relying on symlinked directories. If you're still having problems, you need to provide the actual code you're typing and the real location of your target paths; you can't debug anything without a repeatable and verifiable example.